# Convert datetime string in one timezone to another using offset

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, timezone-offset

I have a datetime string "2018-01-15 01:16:00" which is in EST timezone. I want to convert this into another timezone dynamically using the UTC offset. My javascript code passes this UTC offset as a parameter and the servlet has to convert/format this datetime string to the timezone identified by the provided offset.

I have tried many approaches including the one documented in the [oracle tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/timezones.html) but unable to arrive at a solution.

Below is my code that I am trying, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
private static final String DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE = ZoneId.SHORT_IDS.get("EST");

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String dateTime = "2018-01-15 02:35:00";
    //parse the datetime using LocalDateTime
    LocalDateTime defaultDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT));

    //get the datetime in default timezone
    ZoneId defaultZoneId = ZoneId.of(DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE);
    ZonedDateTime defaultZoneDateTime = defaultDateTime.atZone(defaultZoneId);
    System.out.println("EST time: "+defaultZoneDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT)));
    ZonedDateTime utcZonedDateTime = defaultZoneDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    String utcTime = defaultZoneDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT));
    System.out.println("UTC : "+utcTime);

    //IST timezone
    ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of("+05:30");
    OffsetDateTime offsetDate = OffsetDateTime.of(utcZonedDateTime.toLocalDateTime(), offset);
    String targetTimeZone = offsetDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT));
    System.out.printf("target time : "+targetTimeZone);

}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
EST time: 2018-01-15 02:35:00
UTC : 2018-01-15 07:37:00
target time : 2018-01-15 07:37:00
```

Expected target time : `2018-01-15 13:05:00`

Comment: First thing to check - what do you *really* mean by "EST"? Do you mean "Eastern Time" (which is UTC+5 or UTC+6 depending on the time of year) or genuinely "Eastern Standard Time" (which is UTC+5 all year round)? It's pretty much *always* better to use a full time zone ID e.g. America/New_York.

Comment: Next: providing a complete example with actual output is great, but it would be a lot more helpful if you'd provide the *expected* output as well.

Comment: Thanks, I mean genuinely "Eastern Standard Time" because this datetime string is coming from a 3rd party API and doesn't give accurate information.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet I have added expected output. The code which I have posted is a complete example with hardcoded input datetime string.

Comment: (My earlier comments should have mentioned UTC-5 and UTC-4 rather than UTC+5 and UTC+6 btw.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The immediate problem is this line:

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDate = OffsetDateTime.of(utcZonedDateTime.toLocalDateTime(), offset);
```

That's saying you want the same *local* date/time, but with the specified offset. That changes which instant in time is being represented.

Instead, you really want to represent the same *instant* in time, but at a particular offset. So the shortest fix is:

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDate = utcZonedDateTime.toInstant().atOffset(offset);
```

However, there are a number of other aspects which could do with changing:

- Prefer `ZoneOffset.UTC` to `ZoneId.of("UTC")`
- Using `EST` as a time zone is confusing - it's not clear whether you expect it to mean "Eastern Time" (changing between EST and EDT) or pure standard time of UTC-5. Assuming you actually mean "Eastern Time" it would be better to use `America/New_York` as a zone ID.
- It's unclear what you want to happen if the input string represents a skipped or ambiguous value in Eastern time. These happen around DST transitions.

Next, you don't need to convert the `ZonedDateTime` in Eastern time into a `ZonedDateTime` in UTC at all. Either convert it directly to an instant:

```
OffsetDateTime target = defaultZoneDateTime.toInstant().at(offset);
```

Or create a `ZonedDateTime` for the target instead:

```
ZonedDateTime target = defaultZoneDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(offset);
```

Given that an offset isn't *really* a time zone, I'd probably go with the first of these.

Answer (score 5):

You're using

```
OffsetDateTime.of(utcZonedDateTime.toLocalDateTime(), offset)
```

to create your target. You're thus constructing an OffsetDateTime in the target offset, having a LocalDateTime equal to the LocalDateTime in the UTC zone.

What you want is the exact same transformation as the one you're using to go from the EST time to UTC: keep the same instant, but go to a different timezone:

```
defaultZoneDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(offset);
```

or, if you really want an OffsetDateTime and not a ZonedDateTime:

```
OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(defaultZoneDateTime.toInstant(), offset);
```

Comment: It’s probably just my taste, but to get an `OffsetDateTime` I’d go for `defaultZoneDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(offset).toOffsetDateTime()`.